# How to always link to the latest raw release of a file on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to setup a domain name to always forward to the URL for the latest tag release of a bash script on Github. I can then use this to curl the latest version without having to manually update the domain name to point at each new release. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do it.

This URL points to the latest v0.0.1 release:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saltedlolly/diginode-tools/v0.0.1/diginode-installer.sh

Obviously, when I create a tag for v0.0.2 it won't point to it automatically. Is there a way to always link to the latest tag version? Something like:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saltedlolly/diginode-tools/tag/latest/diginode-installer.sh

I have not been able to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is possible to do this in a single URL, but the github api allows you to get information about the latest release, see:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-the-latest-release

You should be able to string that together with the above.